# OS X says 90GB of Apps

Tags: macos, storage

I have an SSD of 250GB, and in the Storage view of about this Mac it's write I have close to 90GB of apps, when clearly the applications folder is only 18GB. I can hardly believe that system applications and background apps take up nearly 75GB of space ?

Where do the 75GB comes from?

Comment: What exactly is your question (or the problem you want to solve)?

Comment: Does OS X count app-specific data in /Library towards the 'apps' figure?

Comment: Please download DaisyDisk to check where the space is going.

Answer (score 0):

To get a visual representation of what is stored on a disk, including applications, try using [GrandPerspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net).

> GrandPerspective is a small utility application for Mac that graphically shows the disk usage within a file system. It can help you to manage your disk, as you can easily spot which files and folders take up the most space. It uses a so called tree map for visualisation. Each file is shown as a rectangle with an area proportional to the file's size. Files in the same folder appear together, but their placement is otherwise arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Not all applications come from `/Applications`.

Try pressing Option-Command-Space to bring up Spotlight search in a Finder window.

After that, click the plus (+) button, located at the near top-right corner of the Finder window.

Then, you should see a new bar that says "Kind is Any."

Click on "Any," then, click on "Application."

You should immediately see all your applications on your Mac!

Comment: This would be a decent start - from the question it's not even clear if the spotlight database that builds up the space estimate is correct. This would be a way to check if the user in question has read access to the files that presumably make up "apps" category.

Answer (score -1):

Daisy Disk is a great app that lays out the contents of your hard drive in an easy to understand visual way. It breaks everything down nicely and should give you the answer you're looking for.